# Selecting max date record for each user from multiple table

Tags: sql, database

i have two table and would like to query the data filter by latest date, try using function max but don't know how to apply it on two table

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+------+
| member id | member name | internet provider | date |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+------+
| 1         | Sam         | c                 | 2014 |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+------+
| 2         | johnny      | a                 | 2016 |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+------+


+-----------+-------------+--+-----------+-------------------+------+
| table A   |             |  | table B   |                   |      |
+-----------+-------------+--+-----------+-------------------+------+
| member id | member name |  | member id | internet provider | date |
+-----------+-------------+--+-----------+-------------------+------+
| 1         | Sam         |  | 1         | a                 | 2012 |
+-----------+-------------+--+-----------+-------------------+------+
| 2         | Johnny      |  | 1         | b                 | 2013 |
+-----------+-------------+--+-----------+-------------------+------+
| 3         | Amanda      |  | 1         | c                 | 2014 |
+-----------+-------------+--+-----------+-------------------+------+
|           |             |  | 2         | c                 | 2012 |
+-----------+-------------+--+-----------+-------------------+------+
|           |             |  | 2         | b                 | 2013 |
+-----------+-------------+--+-----------+-------------------+------+
|           |             |  | 2         | a                 | 2016 |
+-----------+-------------+--+-----------+-------------------+------+
```

Comment: Can you please also share with us what you have tried to solve the problem?

Comment: You are not clear. You are not saying what you mean. Please use more words and sentences. Eg What are you summarizing, but not *explaining* by "query the data filter by latest date"? Please read and act on [mcve]. PS 1. If you don't know how to summarize using 2 tables then make one table first. 2 What do the 2? 3? tables here have to do with what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at "Aggregate functions". Basically you will join the tables in your preferred way and then use `group by`. Something along the lines of:

```
select member_name, max(date)
from tableA, tableB
where tableA.member_id = tableB.member_id
group by member_name
```

What to do about "ties". There is one thing to be aware of: if you also want the internet provider, you have to figure out how to determine it. let's say the most recent date for member Sam was 2014. What if there are two different internet providers both with the same most recent date? You can try and just add internet provider to your query but databases differ in how they treat that situation. (You don't say which one you are using.) You may have to use a subquery to find the max.

Comment: @philipxy i agree it wasn't that well written but the title was fairly understandable to me, and i prefer to encourage new folks by giving some information.